Confusing U-sub answer which does not match text
The problem is $ \int(1+ \frac{1}{x})^{-3} \frac{1}{x^{2}} dx  $.
I let u = $(1+ \frac{1}{x})$.
So du = $-\frac{1}{x^{2}} dx$
Since this derivative appears inside the integral I am left with in the "U" domain as:
$-\int u^{-3} du$
Thi gives:  $- (-)\frac{u^{-2}}{2}       $
$=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{u^{2}}$
Converting back to the x domain I get:
$\frac{1}{2}$ $ \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}^{2} +C     $
The square is for just the term in the deomoniator but I can't seem to Ajax it. And squaring the numerator doesn't affect the problem.
This is NOT the answer in the text.  Am I making some critical error?
The text method simplifies the $(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ term in the original integral and cancels the $\frac{1}{x^{}2}$ term.
I can see how this works but I can't figure out why my method doesn't produce the same answer and my answer seems quicker and easier.  Any help?  Am I missing a concept?

I'll be honest, I have no clue what you're referring to when you explain the textbook's solution. Could you write their steps explicitly?

I don't see a $(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ term in the original integrand.

It would have been better if you had at least shown the final result that appears in the text. You could still add that information to the question.

Here's another solution of the same integral:
\begin{align}
\int \left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{-3} \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx
&= \int  \frac{x}{(x+1)^3}\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int \left( \frac{x+1}{(x+1)^{3}} - \frac{1}{(x+1)^3}\right)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\,\mathrm dx - \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^3}\,\mathrm dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{x+1} -\frac{1}{2(x+1)^2} + C.
\end{align}
Now let's take your solution and find the difference between it and this solution (not including the constants):
$$ \frac12\cdot\frac1{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^2} - \left(-\frac{1}{x+1} -\frac{1}{2(x+1)^2}\right). $$
Work out what the value of that entire expression is. If you're careful, it will simplify to a constant. That proves that your solution and mine are really the same, because the solution of an indefinite integral is defined only up to the arbitrary constant that may be added to it.
If the solution in the text is different from mine, try the same method of taking differences between solutions. If there's no error in the text and you simplify correctly, you'll get a constant result there too.
